# Linux crontab doesn't appear to be working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to use a cron job on linux to back up my minecraft server every 24 hours. The crontab looks like this:

```
00 00 * * * bash /home/pi/wgsanarchy/backup.sh
```

And backup.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

var=$(date +"%FORMAT_STRING")
now=$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")

tar -zcvf $now-backup.tar.gz /home/pi/wgsanarchy
gupload $now-backup.tar.gz WGSAnarchy
rm /home/pi/$now-backup.tar.gz
```

(The gupload line pushes the file to my google drive)

I've tried to change the time so I can see if it works, but so far I don't think it does.
Can anyone see any errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand why people undervoting instead of helping each other.

This is a common error in Linux bash script when binaries of tar, gunload and so on are not found at the current directory. To solve the issue, write the `PATH` variable at the beginning of the bash script. Just execute `echo $PATH;` in your terminal/bash and copy the result to make `PATH` variable like this

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin;
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean to put this at the beginning of my contab? The sh script worked fine when i tested it

Comment: Your welcome Dear William. Putting this inside of the sh script is enough